# how to fix System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object in apex class using Map<parentId, child>?

Tags: apex, batch

Getting the error in line " taskObj.OwnerId = ConMap.get(ben.contact__c).contact__r.OwnerId;" becasue the ownerid field is on contact.

Contact is the parent of benefit, Here I am getting all the benefits in start method. I want to add contactid only once if it has more than one child for that I used SET. I want to use maps as I need to get the contact OwnerId field from contact object which I am fetching in the query in start method. How do I Access contact.ownerId field using a map? below is the code.

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    Query='select contact__r.ownerId, contact__c, Task_creation_date__c, Status__c, task_created__c, type__c from Benefit__c Where Task_creation_date__c= TODAY AND Status__c IN (\'Active\',\'Pending\') AND Task_created__c =FALSE AND Type__c!=\'Short Term Medical\' AND Contact__c!=NULL';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);            
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Benefit__c> scope){

    List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
    Map<id,benefit__c> ConMap = new map<id,benefit__c>();
    for (Benefit__c b : scope) 
    {
            if(!ConMap.containsKey(b.contact__c))
            {
                ConMap.put(b.contact__c, b);
            }
            b.task_created__c = TRUE;
     }
    system.debug('contact and its benefit------'+ConMap);
     for(Benefit__c ben : ConMap.values())
       {
        Task taskObj = new Task();
                        taskObj.OwnerId = ben.Contact__r.ownerId;
                        taskObj.ActivityDate = System.Today();
                        taskObj.Status = 'Open';
                        taskObj.Priority = 'Normal';
                        taskObj.Subject = 'Courtesy Call Task';
                        taskObj.WhoId = ben.Contact__c;
                        taskObj.Description = 'Courtesy Call Task';
                        taskObj.Type = 'Other';
                        taskObj.Sub_Type__c = 'Other';

            taskList.add(taskObj);

        }
```

I want to populate contact ownerid as the task ownerid but how do I access it from the map and keep the unique contact id in the map?

initial Code :

```
    Query='select contact__c, Task_creation_date__c, Status__c, task_created__c, type__c from Benefit__c Where Task_creation_date__c= TODAY AND Status__c IN (\'Active\',\'Pending\') AND Task_created__c =FALSE AND Type__c!=\'Short Term Medical\'';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Benefit__c> scope){
    // process each batch of records

    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
    set<id> conset = New set<id>();
    for (Benefit__c b : scope) {
            conset.add(b.contact__c);
            b.task_created__c = TRUE;
     }

     recordsProcessed = conset.size();
     List<Contact> tempList = new List<Contact>();
     tempList = [Select Id,OwnerId, firstname from Contact where Id IN:(conset)];
     if(tempList.size()>0)
      {
       for(Contact con : tempList)
       {
        Task taskObj = new Task();
                        taskObj.OwnerId = con.OwnerId;
                        taskObj.ActivityDate = System.Today();
                        taskObj.Status = 'Open';
                        taskObj.Priority = 'Normal';
                        taskObj.Subject = 'Courtesy Call Task';
                        taskObj.WhoId = con.id;
                        taskObj.Description = 'Courtesy Call Task';
                        taskObj.Type = 'Other';
                        taskObj.Sub_Type__c = 'Other';

            taskList.add(taskObj);

        } //close for statement
    TotalTask = taskList.size();  
   } //close if loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this solution as a separate answer because it is a radically different approach.

If you want to only create one `Task` for each `Contact__c` value, you will need to take a different approach, because **two records with the same `Contact__c` may be processed in separate `execute` blocks**. Batch over an `AggregateResult` query instead to avoid this issue.

```
public with sharing class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<AggregateResult>
{
    public Iterable<AggregateResult> start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return [
            SELECT Contact__c, Contact__r.OwnerId owner FROM Benefit__c
            WHERE Contact__c != null AND ...
            GROUP BY Contact__c, Contact__r.OwnerId
        ];
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<AggregateResult> scope)
    {
        Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (AggregateResult aggregate : scope)
        {
            Id ownerId = (Id)aggregate.get('owner');
            Id contactId = (Id)aggregate.get('Contact__c');

            contactIds.add(contactId);
            tasks.add(new Task(OwnerId=ownerId, /*other fields*/));
        }
        insert tasks;

        List<Benefit__c> benefits = [
            SELECT Id FROM Benefit__c WHERE Contact__c IN :contactIds
        ];
        for (Benefit__c benefit : benefits)
            benefit.Task_Created__c = true;
        update benefits;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) { /*additional logic*/ }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I added my initial code in which to avoid the query in execute method I thought of using maps. Even that code will fail in a scenario when benefit for the same contact will be in different batches. correct? And is there a way can we avoid the query in execute method to update the benefit field?

Comment: You have correctly understood why I recommend this approach instead. I don't think you can avoid using a query in the `execute` method, and I don't think you need to worry about it. Each gets its own set of static governor limits.

Comment: final query :   `   return [
            select contact__r.ownerId owner, contact__c, Task_creation_date__c, Status__c, task_created__c, type__c from Benefit__c Where Task_creation_date__c= TODAY AND Status__c IN ('Active','Pending') AND Task_created__c =FALSE AND Type__c!='Short Term Medical' AND Contact__c!=NULL 
            GROUP BY Contact__c, Contact__r.OwnerId
        ];`
giving me erro  :Field must be grouped or aggregated: Task_Creation_Date__c

Comment: Yes, the error message tells you exactly what's wrong. Once you start grouping by fields, everything in your `SELECT` clause must be wrapped in an aggregation function or included in your `GROUP BY` clause. Why do you need your query to return any of those fields? It does not look like you use them in your `execute` logic.

Comment: you are actually correct, I never realized that, Thank you so much for pointing that out. I have updated the code as per your suggestion and I will continue my unit test now to see if it giving expected result.

Comment: Just `Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch());`.

Answer (score 2):

The below advice pertains to the issues in your code, but the correct fix here is to add a filter to your `QueryLocator`:

```
WHERE Contact__c != null AND /*other clauses*/
```

Now you can just do:

```
Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (Benefit__c benefit : scope)
{
    if (contactIds.contains(benefit.Contact__c)) continue;
    // create task and add to collection
    contactIds.add(benefit.Contact__c);
}
```

---

If you want to stick to your current `Map` and `QueryLocator`, you don't need to get the `Benefit__c` out of the map again, since you are already looping through the `values`. Also, you can check if the `Contact__c` field is null before doing any further processing. And you don't need to check if the `Map` is empty before your `for` loop, since an empty loop does nothing.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

// no isEmpty check necessary
for (Benefit__c benefit : conMap.values())
{
    if (benfit.Contact__c != null)
    {
        Task task = new Task(OwnerId = benefit.Contact__r.OwnerId);
        //other logic
        tasks.add(task);
    }
}
```

---

Also note that if you expect this logic to create one `Task` for each `Benefit__c`, you are mistaken, since two `Benefit__c` records can have the same `Contact__c`, and so you will overwrite the value mapped to that key. If you want one per, you would need a `Map<Id, List<Benefit__c>>`.

```
Map<Id, List<Benefit__c>> contactToBenefits = new Map<Id, List<Benefit__c>>();
for (Benefit__c benefit : scope)
{
    if (benefit.Contact__c == null) continue;
    if (!contactToBenefits.containsKey(benefit.Contact__c))
        contactToBenefits.put(benefit.Contact__c, new List<Benefit__c>());
    contactToBenefits.get(benefit.Contact__c).add(benefit);
}

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (List<Benefit__c> benefits : contactToBenefits.values())
{
    for (Benefit__c benefit : benefits)
    {
        // create task and add to collection
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, silly mistake. But I still need map correct? and what should I do as I want only unique contact ids.

List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
        List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
        set<id> conset = New set<id>();
        Map<id,benefit__c> ConMap = new map<id,Benefit__c>();
        for (Benefit__c b : scope) {
                conset.add(b.contact__c);
if(!conmap.isempty()){
                ConMap.put(b.contact__c, b);
} }
I will remove the Set<id> as I do not need it anymore. correct?

Comment: No you don't need a map at all. Still adding detail to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Adrian. I updated my code in the question, I want to avoid for loop inside for loop. Can you check the updated code in the question is it optimized? I also added the contact__c!=null to the querylocator.

Comment: You don't have any nested loops, and again I don't think you need a `Map` at all. You need one `Task` per `Contact__c`?

Comment: Yes, one task per contact even if the contact has 4 benefits under it.

Comment: After adding the tasks to the list, I am inserting it and updating scope as I want to update a field on each benefit once the tasks are inserted.